# SQL Server Create New Line in XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I am trying to figure out how I can insert a new line between fields in SQL Server 2008.

Current XML:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <ProductID>1</ProductID>
    <ProductName>A.1</ProductName>
  </product>
  <product>
    <ProductID>2</ProductID>
    <ProductName>B.1</ProductName>
  </product>
</products>
```

Desired XML:

```
<products>
  <product>

    <ProductID>1</ProductID>

    <ProductName>A.1</ProductName>

  </product>
  <product>

    <ProductID>2</ProductID>

    <ProductName>B.1</ProductName>

  </product>
</products>
```

Any ideas how I can inject Newline/carriage return in the XML output?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Take the output, insert the lines. That is AFTER sql server.

Comment: sorry...not sure I understand what you mean.  So generate the xmloutput then try to inject the new lines in the sql generated xml?

Comment: I mean you dont do what you want to do in sql server. Makes no sense -xml has no defined formatting, anything is identical. You get the xml as string, then manipulate it as you want. OUTSIDE sql server.

Comment: Ok that is what I was starting to do was convert to string.  Thanks @TomTom